# combined vs. separate backend calls

Tags: java, architecture

I try to figure out the best solution for a use case I'm working on. However, I'd appreciate getting some architectural advice from you guys.

I have a use case where the frontend should display a list of users assigned to a task and a list of users who are not assigned but able to be assigned to the same task.

I don't know what the better solution is:

- have one backend call which collects both lists of users and sends them
  back to the frontend within a new data class containing both lists.
- have two backend calls which collect one of the two lists and send them
  back separately.

The first solution's pro is the single backend call whereas the second solution's pro is the reusability of the separate methods in the backend.

Any advice on which solution to prefer and why?

Is there any pattern or standard I should get familiar with?

Comment: RESTful design would probably prefer two calls because the lists are likely to make sense as separate resources. A more immediate consideration is that if your server is multithreaded or you have multiple servers, two calls can easily be executed in parallel, which might speed things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I stumble across the requirement to get data from a server I start with doing just a single call for, more or less (depends on the problem domain), a single feature (which I would call your task-user-list).

This approach saves implementation complexity on the client's side and saves protocol overhead for transactions (TCP header, etc.).

If performance analysis shows that the call is too slow because it requests too much data (user experience suffers) then I would go with your 2nd solution.

Summed up I would start with 1st approach. Optimize (go with more complex solution) when it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the two calls because of the reusability.  Maybe one day you need add a third list of users for one case and then you'd need to change the method if you would only use one method. But then there may be other use cases which only required the two lists but not the three, so you would need to change code there as well. Also you would need to change all your testing methods. If your project gets bigger this makes your project hard to update or fix. Also all the modifications increase the chances of introducing new bugs as well.

Seeing the methods callable by the frontend of the backend like an interface helps.
In general an interface should be open for extension but closed on what the methods return and require. As otherwise a slight modification leads to various more modifications.